# Obtener datos no duplicados con 2 llaves de filtro

Tags: javascript

Estoy limpiando información de una API, aveces la información viene duplicada, estoy tratando de quedarme únicamente con los que no estén duplicados, los demás serán deshechandos, sin embargo el filtro debe ser por las dos llaves `place y price` ambos deben de tener el mismo valor repetido en todo el arreglo para quitarlos, intenté comparar los objetos pero no me funciona y no tengo idea cómo arreglarlo

Gracias

```js
let data = [
  {place: 1, price: 500},
  {place: 3, price: 355},
  {place: 4, price: 675},
  {place: 1, price: 500},
  {place: 2, price: 345},
  {place: 3, price: 775},
  {place: 7, price: 101},
  {place: 8, price: 500},
  {place: 8, price: 500},
  {place: 1, price: 501},
  {place: 7, price: 101},
];

let unique = data.filter( ( v, pos) => {
  return !data.includes( v );
});

console.log( unique );
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el objeto [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set), el cual te permite almacenar valores únicos de cualquier tipo.

```js
let data = [
  {place: 1, price: 500},
  {place: 3, price: 355},
  {place: 4, price: 675},
  {place: 1, price: 500},
  {place: 2, price: 345},
  {place: 3, price: 775},
  {place: 7, price: 101},
  {place: 8, price: 500},
  {place: 8, price: 500},
  {place: 1, price: 501},
  {place: 7, price: 101},
];

let set = new Set( data.map( JSON.stringify ) )
let arrSinDuplicaciones = Array.from( set ).map( JSON.parse );

console.log( arrSinDuplicaciones );
```

Comment: Muy elegante la respuesta sensei, podrías explicarme un poco más la solución, no entiendo bien que hace.